# Why does product rule fail here? (Combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I want to find the number of ways to pick $2$ balls out of a box of $4$ balls.

I know that ${}^nC_r$ is the number of ways of selecting $r$ objects from $n$, so the number of ways to pick $2$ balls out of a box of $4$ is simply ${}^4C_2=6$.

Now I want to to do the same but by using [product rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) this time.

Number of ways to choose first ball is $4$ and number of ways to choose second is $3$ but $4 \cdot 3=12$ and I **understand** that's because I've counted the same combination twice. For example, say the $4$ balls are $B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4$ then I have once selected $\{B_1,B_2\}$ and then $\{B_2,B_1\}$.

Now here's my question: **Why** did the product rule fail here? I followed exactly what that rule told me to, but I still ended up with an incorrect answer? Let me be more specific— I think the product rule as it is stated is incomplete but I cannot exactly put my finger on what condition is missing from the rule to make it true.

Note: My question is not "How did I end up over counting?" I know that. My question is "Why did the product rule fail?"

Comment: The product rule gives the correct answer to the question "how many ways can I select a first and second ball out of a box of four different balls." There are four ways of selecting a first ball, and 3 ways of selecting a second ball, and a total of 12 ways of selecting the first and second balls. The problem is that what you are counting are *ordered* choices, whereas what you want to count is something else.

Comment: Number of possibilities for FIRST ball is $4$, for SECOND is $3$. Then product rule, $4\times 3=12$. Pay attention to the word first and second and let them sink in

Comment: To the downvoter: Why is this question downvoted? The question is sincere. I have shown what I have done and know. Formatting looks good. What else do you want me to, offer my left kidney to the Aztec Gods?

Comment: I was the downvoter, because there is not enough here to work with. If you had given some reasons why you think the product rule should be able to applied, then this would be a good question, because we could explain what is wrong with your reasoning. Since you have not shared your reasoning, all we can do is guess at why you think the product rule applies here. Also, for a question about the details of the product rule, you should state the product rule in detail (not just link it), again so we can easily point out which assumptions of the product rule are violated.

Comment: Also, I cannot understand the difference between "How did I end up overcounting?" and "Why did the product rule fail?". The product rule failed by overcounting, so these seem like the same thing.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Then explain your downvote when you downvote. Don't just downvote and run away like a troll. If you don't understand something, ask! Or how would I come to know if I need to improve my question? Also, people often aren't able to ask the right questions because they don't know what they don't know, so they try best to form a question on what they think they don't know. If everyone knew what they didnt know, there wouldn't be as many questions on this site. In any case, I think most of everyone else understood exactly what I was askin so I don't think it was that bad a question.

Comment: You know why you over-counted. That is the reason the product rule failed. The product rule requires that for two choices $A, B$ that every valid combination of (choice from $A$, choice from $B$) gives a unique result. But in your application here, the combinations of, e.g,, $(4,3)$ and $(3,4)$ give the same result. As Mike Earnest has demonstrated, this was because you were incautious in your application of the product rule, and with more caution it can applied here to give a valid answer. And yes, the Wikipedia article and the Cornell lecure notes failed to adequately explain this.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you want to apply a theorem such as the product rule, you need to verify the assumptions of the theorem. The product can be stated as follows:

> If you have a tree where the root vertex has $a$ children, and each child of the root has $b$ children, then the number of grandchildren of the root vertex is $a\times b$.

In order to apply the product rule to a problem, you need to find a tree in the form described above whose bottom-most vertices are in bijective correspondence with whatever you are trying to count. In fact, it is possible to find a tree diagram which describes choosing two unordered objects from a set of size 4:

```
          Has 1 -- {1, 4}
       / 
 Has 4 -- Has 2 -- {2, 4}
 /     \
.         Has 3 -- {3, 4}
 \
  \              Missing 1 -- {2, 3}
   \          /  
    Missing 4 -- Missing 2 -- {1, 3}
              \ 
                 Missing 3 -- {1, 2}
```

Since the root has $2$ children, and both children of the root have $3$ children, and since the grandchildren of the root are labeled with each subset of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ of size two exactly once, the product rule implies that the number of subsets is $3\times 2$. This matches the usual value of $\binom 42=\frac{4!}{2!2!}$.

So you see, the product rule *can* apply to this problem. But you are asking, why does the product rule not imply there are $4\times 3$ sets? Well, simply because there does not exist a tree with $4$ branches at top, where each child has $3$ branches, and the leaves are labeled by the subsets of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ with size $2$.

---

All in all, it is not valid to ask "Why does the product rule fail?" The product rule is a tool which is always true; it cannot fail. The only thing that can fail is a specific **attempt** at applying the product rule, and it fails because the assumptions of the theorem are not verified. However, since you have not told us **how** you attempted to apply the product rule to this problem (you simply wrote $4\times 3$, without verifying the assumptions of the product rule), there is no way for us to answer why your attempt at applying it failed. This is why I downvoted your question; you left out this important context.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: The rule as written in Wikipedia is perhaps slightly misleading and maybe even incomplete.

The product rule, as stated in Wikipedia says that if there are $a$ ways of doing something and $b$ ways of doing another thing, then the total number of ways of doing both things is $ab$.

So you're assuming for your case, $a=4$ and $b=3$.

But that isn't quite true! For starters, the number of ways to pick the second thing is *conditional* on the number of ways to do the first thing. Wikipedia never formally defines this rule, but this is mentioned specifically in the following lecture notes: [the product rule only holds for *independent events*](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs280/2004fa/280wk6_x4.pdf).

So what happens when you *don't* have independent events? You discard invalid instances. Why does it remove so many cases? Because your conditional is a lot more complicated than it seems. When doing a count, you actually need to account for valid cases which have already been counted.

Think of the whole counting exercise as a series of you picking two different balls *with the goal of finding distinct pairs*, each conditioned on what you have already picked. For example, one step may look like:

> How many ways can I pick my second ball, conditioned on the fact that my first ball was $B_2$, and that I already saw the pair $(B_1,B_2)$?

Your conditional here is not just the first ball you picked, but also what pairs you have seen before. So, the number of choices you have is effectively less.

Edit: As Arturo pointed out in a comment, the product rule tells you how many ways there are to draw a first ball followed by a second ball, agnostic of whatever choices you may have made in previous draws. That is not the experiment you want. For a draw to be valid, you must draw a fresh pair, irrespective of order. Consider the following: you do the following draws:
$$(1,2),(1,3),(4,1).$$
Now you want to do your fourth draw. Technically, you've drawn $1$ on the first draw only twice. So you should have one more turn, right? But actually you don't, because the irrelevance of order means that $(4,1)$ took care of that. How do you get $4\times 3$? For every one of the four balls, you should get three tries. But here you don't. Because You don't just care about how many ways to draw a first ball and a second ball, you care about the pair itself. The answer to the former is what the product rule gives you.

Comment: I can't seem to open the link for the lecture notes you have provided.

Comment: @William the link itself is: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs280/2004fa/280wk6_x4.pdf , maybe it might work by copy pasting it somewhere? In general this should not be hard to find.

Comment: The pdf defines independent events as $A$ and $B$ are independent if the **number of choices** for doing $B$ is the same regardless of which choice you made for $A$. But by that definition, my events ARE independent because **number of choices** for second ball is $3$ regardless of which ball is chosen the first time.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to define the terms "event" and "independent event" BOTH? I think that would clear up a lot of my confusion, thank you!

Comment: An event is a specific outcome of an experiment. Here, for example, when you pick two balls, an event may be $X_1=B_1$ (where $X_i$ is the ball picked in the $i$-th attempt). Now consider the random variables $X_1, X_2$. Are these two independent? They are not. Why? If $X_1=B_1$, $X_2$ *cannot* be $B_1$. o put it crudely, the sample space changes. Maybe this example helps? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3630745/257404

Go with the intuitive meaning; if one affects the other, they're dependent. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)

Comment: @William - the pdf does not mention "Events" at all. You got that from some other source. The problem is, "event" is a term from probability, not combinatorics, which is what you are discussing here. Unfortunately, Boshu's reply is also about probability, not combinatorics. The pdf

Comment: @PaulSinclair The pdf says "there are $n(A)$ ways to do $A$..." So what is $A$, if not an event?

Comment: @William - I had stopped that comment and was planning to reword it, because I felt the wording I had used was problematic. Unfortunately, I apparently saved it instead of cancelling. Sorry for the confusion. But still, the pdf does not make any mention of "events" - that part was your own inclusion. You could call $A$ an "action", though that doesn't really address the problem. But I do not think it fully matches the probabilistic concept of an "event".

Comment: @PaulSinclair I could call it whatever but I need a definition of that whatever term because I need to understand if you an I are on the same page. Go ahead, let me know what do you call it, and how is it different from the probabilistic concept of an event so I know what is going on because I'm seriously confused.